# Finding a point on a surface that is the closest to a specific point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

I have $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and need to find the point on that surface that is closest to $(3,4,0)$.

Absolutely no clue about where to start. This one has me puzzled. I was suggested that I should use Lagrange multipliers but I don't see how finding a max or min value would help me here, plus I don't have a constraint function...

I do know that distance is $\sqrt{(x1-x0)^2 + (y1-y0)^2 + (z1-z0)^2}$ so I'd plug in my point as $\sqrt{(x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2 + (z-0)^2}$ but that's as far as I got.

Comment: Another way to say "closest" is "minimum distance". Do you know any ways to find the minimum of something using calculus?

Comment: Right, that's where I'd use Lagrange multipliers then. But not sure how... I usually do it using a function and a constraint, then find gradients for both and set an equation where one of them is multiplied by $\lambda$, then find x, y, z values. I'm not sure how to get to that kind of setup with the information I'm given.

Comment: This got me thinking whether there exists a way of using singular value decomposition $A = U W V^{T}$ on nonlinear surfaces... It should work, I am just unable to type a whole answer on cellphone

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: the distance can be modeled by the function $f(x,y) = \sqrt{(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2+(\sqrt{x^2+y^2} - 0)^2}= \sqrt{x^2-6x+9+y^2-8y+16+x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2-6x-8y+25}$. From this you can take the partial derivatives $f_x = 0, f_y= 0$ and solve for the critical points. From this the answer is around the corner...

Comment: Thank you @DeepSea :) I'm actually a bit lost where you said that $f_x = 0, f_y= 0$. I actually got huge partial derivatives for x and y (because of the square root)... why do you say they're 0?